# data-bind: value - parenthesis - observable

Tags: html, data-binding, knockout.js

I started working with knockout a few months ago and so far it is being a very good road. Today when I was working with some inputs in my html I came across a very boring issue that took me a while to figure out. Here is my code:

```
<div class="add-box" style="display:none;" id="new-user">
   <textarea placeholder="Name" data-bind="value : name"></textarea>
</div>

<script>
    function UserViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.name= ko.observable('');
    }


    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new  UserViewModel(), document.getElementById('new-user'));
    })
</script>
```

This code works fine, but the first time that I did was like this:

```
<textarea placeholder="Name" data-bind="value : name()"></textarea>
```

The only difference between them are the parenthesis () at the end of the name property. Since this is a observable one I thought that the parenthesis would be necessary in order to make the 2-way-binding. But with them, whenever I change the value of the textarea the viewmodel is not update accordingly, if I remove everything works.

Could you explain why on this case I have to remove the parenthesis, and why in other scenarios, like when I used data-bind="text: I have to put them??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the magic with KO: *special "Observable" function-objects*.

When you use parenthesis, you *evaluate* the observable (which is just a special function) which results in a *value* that *breaks* "live" data-binding: in this case the underlying *value* (say, a string) is bound, but not the *observable* from which the value was obtained.

The underylying bindings are (usually) smart enough to deal with both observables and non-observable values. However, bindings can *only* update observables and can *only* detect Model changes through observables.

So, *usually*, do not include parenthesis when using *obervables* with declarative data-binding.

Passing the *observable* will make sure the Magic Just Works and allow the View and Model to stay in sync. Changes to said *bound observable* will trigger the appropriate binding update (e.g. so that it can update the HTML) even if the binding does not itself need to update the observable/Model.

---

However, *in some rarer cases*, you just want the value *right then* and you *never want the binding to update* from/to the Model. In these rarer cases, using parenthesis - to force value extraction and not bind the observable itself - is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using `jquery.tmpl` ,

and knockout 2.2.0 works with jquery.tmpl, when I upgrade to knockout 3.0, I got this problem

when I use this one, It somehow get conflict with Knockoutjs builtin template/

Removing `jquery.tmpl.js` resolves my problem.